# OCR Python get wrong characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr

I am trying to recognize text from this image

[image]

here is my trial

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Path of working folder on Disk
src_path = "E:/PythonApps/characterRecognitionWithTuneWithVoice/"

def get_string(img_path):
# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Convert to gray
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# Write image after removed noise
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

#  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

# Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"), lang='eng')

# Remove template file
#os.remove(temp)

return result


print '--- Start recognize text from image ---'
print get_string(src_path + "Untitled.png")

print "------ Done -------"
```

but i got wrong text characters as below

```
um msmv unuur
```

so any idea what happen or what should i do to get the text?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: try cropping the image to remove the logo, so you only provide the text, and see if it works.

Comment: It also looks like the characters is truncated - there might not be enough thickness for the OCR to make a positive identification of the characters.  If it cropping out what it thinks are the characters, then it's quite likely that it is cropping the top couple of pixels off - do the crop yourself in an editor, and see how what is left could easilly come out as what you get from the OCR function.

Comment: i tried after crop the text without logo and i got the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be there is something wrong with your eng tessdata, which tesseract OCR version and eng tessdata you are using?

Try replacing this [eng tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast/blob/master/eng.traineddata) in tessdata directory

p.s. your code and image give exact output you desire with the configuration: [eng tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast/blob/master/eng.traineddata) and tesseract version 4.x in my machine.

Comment: i totally forgot that question almost 2 years ,and yes the newer version of tesseract fixed it but still need some enhancement

Comment: there are lots of configurable parameters that you can try to improve OCR like segmentation(PSM), OEM, etc.